# Is the result of Bayesian Inference with MCMC reliable since there maybe a big variance?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, bayesian-optimization

I'm new to Bayesian inference and I came across a, maybe simple, question. That is, in many cases, we don't know how the posterior distribution really looks like, and we adapt the result of MCMC, or to say, the expected value as the best estimation to the parameters, but what if the posterior distribution has a very large variance, or is a distribution similar to uniform distribution?

If the posterior distribution has a very large variance or it is something like a uniform distribution, many very different values can be used as the estimations to the parameters and they may be very close to each other in terms of their probabilities.

Comment: Just take more posterior draws.  We typically take around 5,000 - 10,000 draws but if you wait for 50,000 draws you can compute almost any quantity with little simulation error.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes, but I saw many pieces of research that only report the mean value of those sample values but not other characteristics of the posterior distribution. What I want to know is whether the result is meaningless if I found the posterior has a large variance or is close to a uniform distribution through the many sample values.

Comment: The posterior is supposed to have a large width (e.g., variance) if the original sample size N is not large.  The questions is how many posterior samples are needed to well estimate the entire posterior distribution.  Typically the answer is between 4,000 and 50,000 samples.  And if you can compute the posterior distribution well to within a small simulation error you can compute all quantities derived from it, e.g., posterior mean/median.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be mixing two issues:

1. Is using an MCMC approximation reliable?
2. Is returning the average of the MCMC sample a good Bayesian estimate?

Concerning point 1., MCMC may fail to converge to the posterior with a given number of iterations, in which case the resulting sample is not a reliable approximation to a sample from the posterior, no matter which summary is used. When the posterior is rather flat, convergence is actually faster and this should not be a major concern.

Concerning point 2., assuming the Markov chain has reached stationarity (after a burnin step has been eliminated) and each term in the Markov chain is marginally distributed from the posterior, the MCMC sample can mostly be used as any other Monte Carlo sample. The average of the sample is thus an approximation of the posterior expectation. When the posterior has a large variance, this is presumably an estimator with a large variance but the "exact" posterior expectation would similarly have a large variance. Using a more robust loss function would then be recommended, but this has nothing to do with MCMC.

As a general point, Bayesian inference is not concentrating on returning point estimates but instead full distributions with an included assessment of uncertainty/variability.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you probably need to improve your probabilistic model as the current model is probably not the most suitable for mimicking the scenario. Hence, even with high mcmc sample size, the parameters obtained may not be representative of the scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.